# No module named yum centos 7

Tags: python, centos

После обновления python возникла ошибка:

```
# yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.9 (default, Mar  3 2017, 15:03:33)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
 the yum faq at:
 http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq


 # which python
/usr/bin/python
# python -V
Python 2.7.9
# ls -l /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8209704 Mar  3 15:03 /usr/bin/python
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Что выдает `yum --version`

И что будет если сделать 
`ln -s /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum/yum.conf`?

Comment: @nick_gabpe у меня уже была подобна ссылка: `ls -l /etc/yum/yum.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Mar  2 16:13 /etc/yum/yum.conf -> /etc/yum.conf` А `yum --version` выдает тоже самое, что и команда yum

Comment: @nick_gabpe Подумал, что вообще yum удалился, но `rpm -i yum*.rpm
        package yum-3.4.3-150.el7.centos.noarch is already installed`

Comment: А именно `yum --version` выдает версию без ошибок, верно?

Comment: Выдает `yum --version
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.`
А команда `# which yum
/usr/bin/yum
`
@nick_gabpe

Comment: @nick_gabpe А у питона должна быть ссылка из /usr/bin/python?
Например, lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 28  2013 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7

Comment: Да, можно попробовать сделать `ln -s   /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`